# c# preprocessor directives to evaluate a value from configuration manager

Tags: c#

I need to get a value from configuration manager in C# Preprocessor directive 
And want to do as like below,

```
#if  System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Language"].Equals("en-US");
{
bool languageCheck=TRUE
}
#endif
```

Is it possible  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, pre-processors mean "pre-compilation", and at that point it does not know what values are stored in objects or configurations. However, you can add a different build configuration (by clicking on project properties going to build tab), and add the language flag to it to do a similar thing.

[image]

```
public void SayLanguage()
        {
#if en_US
            Console.WriteLine("en_US");
#else
            Console.WriteLine("Language not defined.");
#endif
        }
```

Comment: Can you help me with how it can be achieved by different build configuration.?

Comment: You can see the updated answer. This adds the flag to an existing configuration (here "Debug" configuration). If you want to add a different configuration, then go to Solution > Properties > Configuration Manager > Select "<new>" from the configuration list and follow the instructions.